# Struts2 jQuery Plugin issue with Double Select

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery-plugin

I have a little (I hope) issue trying to use Doubleselect element from Struts2 jQuery plugin  and after searching the internet I found nothing about it so I come here to get your help.
I have a jsp with two struts2 jQuery Plugin selects to get the second select (*Modelo*) loaded based of the item selected from the first one (*Fabricante*).  When the jsp is loaded, the first select is loaded; but when I select an item from this first select, the value of this selected item does not arrive (is value is null) to the action so there is no way to query the values for the second select from database; consequently, second select is never loaded.

I have followed the [sample](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action) from the struts2-jquery-showcase.

Some info about my app:

- struts2 2.3
- tiles
- Spring 3.1 (I have struts2-spring integration)

Following the code snippets from some files

**JSP code for the tiles layout**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<tiles:importAttribute/>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var GB_ROOT_DIR = "res/greybox/";
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="res/greybox/AJS.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="res/greybox/AJS_fx.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="res/greybox/gb_scripts.js"></script>
<...>

        <sj:head jqueryui="true" />

    </head>
    <body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">

             <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
             <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />

<...>
             <tiles:insertAttribute name="content" />

    </body>
</html>
```

**JSP code**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="display" uri="http://displaytag.sf.net"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<...>
<s:form action="nuevaReparacion2" validate="true" onsubmit="return checkSubmit();" name="formulario" method="post">
<...>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="900">
          <tr>
            <td height="2"> Fabricante:
            <s:url id="remoteurl" action="nuevaReparacionCargaModelo"/>
            <sj:select
                    href="%{remoteurl}"
                    id="selectFab"
                    onChangeTopics="reloadModelos"
                    name="idFabricante"
                    list="listFabricantes"
                    listKey="id"
                    listValue="nombre"
                    emptyOption="false"
                    headerKey="-1"
                    headerValue="Seleccione un fabricante"
                    indicator="indicator"
                />
                <img id="indicator"
                    src="res/images/ajax-loader.gif"
                    alt="cargando..."
                    style="display:none"
                />

            </td>
            <td height="2">Modelo:
            <sj:select
                    href="%{remoteurl}"
                    id="selectMod"
                    formIds="formulario"
                    reloadTopics="reloadModelos"
                    name="idModelo"
                    list="listModelos"
                    listKey="id"
                    listValue="nombre"
                    emptyOption="false"
                    headerKey="-1"
                    headerValue="Seleccione un modelo"
                    indicator="indicator2"
                />
                <img id="indicator2"
                    src="res/images/ajax-loader.gif"
                    alt="cargando..."
                    style="display:none"
                />
            </td>

          </tr>
        </table>
<...>
```

**web.xml**

```
<...>
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/spring-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/tiles.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/struts/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>


  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
<...>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<...>
      <interceptor-stack name="authenticationMinimalStack">
        <interceptor-ref name="exception" />
        <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
        <interceptor-ref name="securityInterceptor" />
        <interceptor-ref name="prepare" />
        <interceptor-ref name="checkbox" />
        <interceptor-ref name="multiselect" />
        <interceptor-ref name="chain" />
        <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <!--  <param name="maximumSize">50000000</param> -->
            <param name="maximumSize">80000000</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="staticParams" />
        <interceptor-ref name="params"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="workflow" />
      </interceptor-stack>
<...>
<...>
   <action name="nuevaReparacionCargaModelo" method="cargaModeloFabricante" class="nuevaReparacionAction">
      <interceptor-ref name="authenticationMinimalStack" />
      <result name="pajax" type="json"></result>
    </action>
<...>
```

**Action class code**

```
public class NuevaReparacionAction extends AbstractAction<NuevaReparacionForm> {
<...>
public String init() throws Exception {

        if (model.getListFabricantes() == null) {
            List<Fabricante> listFabricantes = referenceDataService.getAllFabricantes();
            model.setListFabricantes(listFabricantes);

        }
<...>
}
<...>
    public String cargaModeloFabricante()  throws Exception {

        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(idFabricante)){
            List<Modelo> listModelos = referenceDataService.getAllModelosPorFab(idFabricante);
            model.setListModelos(listModelos);
        }

        String res = "pajax";
        return res;
    }
<...>
}
```

**Form class code**

```
public class NuevaReparacionForm extends AbstractActionForm {
<...>
private List<Fabricante> listFabricantes;
    private String idFabricante;
    private List<Modelo> listModelos;
    private String idModelo;
<...>
public List<Fabricante> getListFabricantes() {
        return listFabricantes;
    }

    public void setListFabricantes(List<Fabricante> listFabricantes) {
        this.listFabricantes = listFabricantes;
    }

    public String getIdFabricante() {
        return idFabricante;
    }

    public void setIdFabricante(String idFabricante) {
        this.idFabricante = idFabricante;
    }
    public List<Modelo> getListModelos() {
        return listModelos;
    }

    public void setListModelos(List<Modelo> listModelos) {
        this.listModelos = listModelos;
    }

    public String getIdModelo() {
        return idModelo;
    }

    public void setIdModelo(String idModelo) {
        this.idModelo = idModelo;
    }

<...>
```

**The *Fabricante* bean**

```
public class Fabricante extends AbstractObject<Long> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3767216824782509270L;

    private boolean indRepara;


    public boolean isIndRepara() {
        return indRepara;
    }


    public void setIndRepara(boolean indRepara) {
        this.indRepara = indRepara;
    }




    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }

        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!obj.getClass().equals(getClass())) {
            return false;
        }

        Fabricante castedObj = (Fabricante) obj;
        return ObjectUtils.equals(getId(), castedObj.getId());
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this)
                   .append("id", getId())
                   .append("nombre", getNombre())
                   .toString();
    }
}
```

**The *Modelo* bean**

```
public class Modelo extends AbstractObject<Long> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5167217040308921281L;

    private Fabricante fabricante;


    public Fabricante getFabricante() {
        return fabricante;
    }

    public void setFabricante(Fabricante fabricante) {
        this.fabricante = fabricante;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }

        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!obj.getClass().equals(getClass())) {
            return false;
        }

        Modelo castedObj = (Modelo) obj;
        return ObjectUtils.equals(getId(), castedObj.getId());
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this)
                   .append("id", getId())
                   .append("nombre", getNombre())
                   .toString();
    }
}
```

**The superclass for the beans**

```
public class AbstractObject<T>  {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7717102673045778131L;
    /**
     * The object id
     */
    private T id;
    private String nombre;


    /**
     * Setter for attribute "id"
     * @param id the object id
     *
    public void setId(T id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for attribute "id"
     * @return the object id
     *
    public T getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.